# Error Runtime Error 91 When Opening File with Application.Workbooks.Open()

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to open a CSV file and when the file opens it errors, saying "Run-time error '91': Object variable or With block variable not set". The file still opens on my computer, but it throws the error immediately after opening. I have copied the file path directly copied and pasted to a string variable to ensure it is correct and it is still erroring. I have also encountered 'Run-time error '1004': Unable to read file" in some instances. I am assuming that the file, despite being in CSV format, is unable to be read by VBA because when I open the file manually it has no issues. The file I am trying to open is downloaded from a merchant website and tries to automatically save in "Unicode text" format (despite the website saying it is downloading in CSV format), but I save it as a CSV file instead.

Here is the code I am trying to run which is testing a fraction of the overall code I am building:

```
Sub openBook()
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim wbFilePath As String
    wbFilePath = "" 'filepath directly copied from windows
    wb = Application.Workbooks.Open(fileName:=wbFilePath, ReadOnly:=True)
    Debug.Print "Success"
    wb.Close False
    Set wb = Nothing
End Sub
```

VBA opens the file and immediately throws an error before reaching "Debug.Print "Success", leaving the file open on my computer in ReadOnly mode.

The file path is correct and I have tried to find answers on file formatting being an issue, but I have not come across any definitive answers that have helped. One source that I came across stated that VBA cannot read UTF8, but I am not sure if that is the problem since I am saving the file in CSV. I have tried opening it using "CorruptLoad" with no success.

Side note: I am using Excel 2016.

Any suggestions on how to open this file?

Comment: CSV vs UTF8 is not an either-or distinction: CSV files can be created using ASCII, UTF8, or any other text encoding.  The "Error 91" issue is because you're not using `Set` - that line should be `Set wb = Application.Workbooks.Open(fileName:=wbFilePath, ReadOnly:=True)`

Comment: Sorry, my brain is fried today. Yes that is the problem.